# Compare year from the given date in the XML file using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

My XML File:

```
<Company>
<Employee name="Rutu" Emp_id="E001">
    <Age>22</Age>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <Address>M/3,hului</Address>
    <Department Deptid="D1">Production</Department>
    <Join_date>10/9/2012</Join_date>
    <Salary>50000</Salary>
    </Employee>
<Employee name="Meera" Emp_id="E004">
    <Age>21</Age>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <Address>Behind Raj palace</Address>
    <Department Deptid="D1">Production</Department>
    <Join_date>3/4/2014</Join_date>
    <Salary>80000</Salary>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

My Question is: Select all the employee detail who’s joining date is before
year 2013.
I tried the following Xpath but I am not getting the desired output:
    //Employee[substring(Join_date, 1, 4)<'2013']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is what you need.

```
//Employee[number(substring(Join_date, string-length(Join_date) - 3, 4))<2014]
```

**Just few explanation in case if you wonder what is going on.**

that returns a position to the first number of year. Since you can't know for sure how many characters will be used in a year, f.x: 10/12/2015 vs 1/1/2015.

> string-length(Join_date) - 3

In order to use < > you should have a number, so you need to cast result to number

> number('2015')

Comment: Just a note: if you need this XPath from within XSLT, you will have to write `&lt;` (or alternatively `lt` in XSLT 2.0) instead of `<` (the latter is a reserved character in XML).